# generate gif with images2gif

Tags: python, gif, animated-gif

I am generating a gif with images2gif from some .png pictures. I am using the following script:

```
__author__ = 'Robert'    
from images2gif import writeGif
from PIL import Image
import os

file_names = sorted((fn for fn in os.listdir('/home/manager/Desktop/sf_linux_shared/project/prueba') if fn.endswith('.png')))
#['animationframa.png', 'animationframb.png', ...] "


images = [Image.open(fn) for fn in file_names]


size = (150,150)
for im in images:
    im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

print writeGif.__doc__

filename = "my_gif.GIF"
writeGif(filename, images, duration=0.2)
```

however I have the following error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cosa.png'

cosa.png is one of the pictures I want to create the gif with. The problem seems to be in:

```
images = [Image.open(fn) for fn in file_names]
```

but I cannot detect it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open(filename)` looks in the current working directory if `filename` is not an
absolute path. The current working directory is the directory from which the script is run.

Either use `os.chdir` to change the working directory, or make all your filenames absolute:

```
WORKDIR = '/home/manager/Desktop/sf_linux_shared/project/prueba'
file_names = sorted((os.path.join(WORDIR, fn) 
                     for fn in os.listdir(WORKDIR) if fn.endswith('.png')))
```